# Getting closing div to print correctly on foreach loop

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, curl

I'm printing some items in a json object into a grid, and I'm trying to print out the closing div tag in the right place, but its missing off the closing div of 'row-fluid'. My code is:

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/header.php');
?>
<div id="content" class="row-fluid">
    <?php
    if (!isset($session['items'])) {
        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/andrewwelch/projects?api_key=n1LTMZFd9zez1j6jLFYBA7GyWFewPsrb');
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
        $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);
        $projects = (json_decode($query));
    } else {
       $projects = $session['items'];
    }
    ;
    $i = 0;
    foreach (reset($projects) as $value) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            print '<div class="row-fluid">';
        }
        if (($i % 4) == 0) {
            print '<div class="row-fluid">';
        }
        print '<div class="span3" style="height:200px;">';
        $covers = (Array) $value->covers;
        print '<img src="' . reset(array_slice($covers, '1')) . '"/>';
        print '<span class="thumb_title">' . $value->name . '</span>';
        print '</div>';
        if (($i % 4) == 4) {
        print '</div>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the first `if` inside the `foreach`, the second `if` already handles that condition.  You should remove that as that's adding extra opening `div` when the loop starts.

Secondly as Jim has pointed out `($i % 4) == 4)` will never be true.  You want to do `($i % 4) == 0)`.

Try the following:

```
$i = 0;
foreach (reset($projects) as $value) {
    if (($i % 4) == 0) {
        print '<div class="row-fluid">';
    }
    print '<div class="span3" style="height:200px;">';
    $covers = (Array) $value->covers;
    print '<img src="' . reset(array_slice($covers, '1')) . '"/>';
    print '<span class="thumb_title">' . $value->name . '</span>';
    print '</div>';
    if (($i % 4) == 0) {
        print '</div>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

**Update:**

After seeing OP's desired output:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($projects as $value) {
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        if ($i != 0) {
            print "</div>";
        }
        print '<div class="row-fluid">';
    }

    print '<div class="span3" style="height:200px;">';
    $covers = (Array) $value->covers;
    print '<img src="' . reset(array_slice($covers, '1')) . '"/>';
    print '<span class="thumb_title">' . $value->name . '</span>';
    print '</div>';

    $i++;
}
print "</div>";
```

Comment: this prints the first element in the row-fluid div, then 3 with the span class then one with the row-fluid div etc etc...

Comment: @AndrewWelch, could you add your expected output, a couple of rows.

Comment: The aim is to print <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div><div class="span3"></div></div>

Comment: @AndrewWelch, Please see my update.  I think this solves your requirement.

Comment: Hi @vinodahikary- this doesn't print but will look into later on. Thanks. Andy

Comment: @AndrewWelch, It might not be visible on your browser based on the styles applied, please check source and it should give you the expected output.

Comment: perfect you had just missed reset($projects) from the foreach

Answer (score 1):

```
($i % 4) == 4)
```

Is never true. Mod 4 will return 0,1,2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach (reset($projects) as $value) {
        print '<div class="row-fluid">';
        print '<div class="span3" style="height:200px;">';
        $covers = (Array) $value->covers;
        print '<img src="' . reset(array_slice($covers, '1')) . '"/>';
        print '<span class="thumb_title">' . $value->name . '</span>';
        print '</div>';
        if (($i++%4) == 0) {
            print '</div><div class="row-fluid">';
        }
    }
    if(($i%4) != 0)// if in case the the loop not end the div tag
        print '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: this doens't print the end of each row tag corerctly

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($i % 4) == 0)
```

this will work.